# StormCrawler moving from 1.6 to 1.8

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I'm facing the following error while trying to switch to SC 1.8 (I was on 1.6 before). I've installed Storm 1.2.1, ES 6.2.2 as recommended, adapted the ES configuration and my ES seed injector topology. However, when I launch it, here is what I get:

```
4845 [Thread-34-enqueue-executor[5 5]] ERROR c.d.s.e.p.StatusUpdaterBolt - Can't connect to ElasticSearch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no hosts provided
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder.<init>(RestClientBuilder.java:69) ~[patent-crawler-1.8.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.builder(RestClient.java:120) ~[patent-crawler-1.8.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getClient(ElasticSearchConnection.java:96) ~[patent-crawler-1.8.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchConnection.getConnection(ElasticSearchConnection.java:166) ~[patent-crawler-1.8.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt.prepare(StatusUpdaterBolt.java:141) [patent-crawler-1.8.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5043$fn__5056.invoke(executor.clj:803) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]
```

Had anyone faced a similar problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you have in the config for *es.status.addresses*? The old value should be compatible

Comment: Hello Julien,
I've tried localhost, localhost:9300, http://localhost:9200

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my mistake, I was too quick with a copy/paste in my ES yaml. I had the indexer entry (es.indexer.addresses) replicated for all indices...
Now it's working fine.
Thank you Julien for the hint!